# Can I close a manually opened tab using Selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to close tabs having a specific URL that was not opened using webdriver.
So when I search all solutions contained this line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

which actually opens a new window and control that. I also tried

```
print(driver.window_handles)
```

that actually does not print any window handles that were opened manually. My requirement is something like I open a lot of geeksforgeeks.com(let's say) tabs while working. I want a script that will close all geeksforgeeks tabs in my browser.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
String parent=driver.getWindowHandle();

Set<String>s=driver.getWindowHandles();

Iterator<String> I1= s.iterator();
while(I1.hasNext())
{
String child_window=I1.next();

if(!parent.equals(child_window))
{
driver.switchTo().window(child_window);

window_title = driver.switchTo().window(child_window).getTitle();
if (window_title == "geeksforgeeks.com")
{
driver.close();
}

}
//switch to the parent window
driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

Kindly change the above code as per your requirement.

Comment: It is not working I think, if a convert it to python code it is like getting the list of window_handles first. And print(driver.window_handle) show it can't detect windows that are opened manually. Thanks for your answer anyways